# Is it uncommon / unnatural to say "It sometimes happens" instead of "It happens"?

Tags: american-english

The English textbooks used in schools in my country Iran have been written by my countrymen (non-native speakers). That's why I often have doubts about the naturalness of some of the things in the textbooks. For example, there is a conversation in the textbook. It goes like this:

A: I twisted my ankle last year.
B: It sometimes happens.

"It sometimes happens" is a well-formed sentence; however, it is exactly what we say in Azeri and Persian languages. I have always heard "It happens" or even "Happens" in American movies. Is it better to omit "sometimes" from that sentence and explain to the students that it's the more natural way of expressing that idea?

Comment: _It sometimes happens_ is a perfectly natural sentence; whether it would be used in that particular context I don't know, because I wouldn't give a reply like that.

Comment: The default response to hearing that someone hurt themselves would be sympathy, and "It sometimes happens" is usually used to reassure people that what they did isn't their fault rather than to express sympathy.

Comment: @Esther  Thank you. So if the function of the sentence in this dialogue is not to express sympathy, then perhaps the sentence "It sometimes happens" literally means "Sometimes people twist their ankles." In that case, there would be nothing wrong with the sentence and the problem would be solved. Am I correct?

Comment: yes, there is nothing wrong with the sentence, I was just wondering if in your native language that phrase might be used in a different context than it would be in English (for example to express sympathy, which it doesn't in English), but if that's the intended meaning, it works perfectly well.

Comment: @Esther: Well, now that I think about it, you're right, we don't say "It sometimes happens" to express sympathy in my native language (I'm bilingual, Azeri and Persian). In my own language, I mostly expect to hear "It happens" when someone is apologizing for something and we tell them "That's OK. It happens." rather than using that sentence to sympathize with someone to whom something bad has happened.

Answer (score 1):

"It sometimes happens" can be a natural usage in English. I mostly use it at the start od the sentence, such as:

> It sometimes happens that one finds it hard to choose between two good things.

I would not be likely to use "It sometimes happens" as a response to:

> I twisted my ankle last year.

Nor would I use "It happens" as a response, but I can imagine someone I know using "it happens" as a response to that statement more easily than "It sometimes happens". But responding with either suggests a lack of sympathy or caring.  I can imagine a fictional character such as Same Spade [from *The Maltese Falcon*] making such a response, but Spade is the prototypical "hard boiled" character, who conceals his emotions even when he has them, n often doesn't have any soft emotions.

There is nothing wrong, or even particularly unnatural with the response "It sometimes happens", provided the intent is to show a somewhat dismissive reaction. If that is not the intent, neither "it happens" nor "It sometimes happens" are good fits, in my view.